# A ticket is considered lucky if the sum of the first 3 digits equaled the sum of the last 3 digits.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Show that the sum of these tickets between 000000 and 999999 are divisible by 7.
I started by thinking that I would need to find an interval where the lucky tickets would sum to a multiple of seven and then use that interval to find all of the interval sums between 000000 and 999999, but I have no efficient way of actually finding the numbers. What is this efficient method?

Comment: Hint: $7$ divides $1001$.

Comment: @EthanBolker I still don't see how that helps as my examples aren't divisible by 1001.

Comment: any time both sets of digits are the same in the same order the number will be a multiple of 1001.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What is both sets of digits? And what do you mean by in the same order?

Comment: 999,999 both sets, are the first three, and the last three. In this case they are all nines and in the case of say: 127127  the digits in these two sets are in the same order.

Comment: I see, but how would non-repeating digits work? How could I show that they some to a number with repeating digits?

Comment: Consider the action of $S_3\times S_3$ on the set of working numbers and add inside each orbit

Comment: I think you'll find quite a few of your wanted values do in fact have the same digits ( but relaxing the ordering condition). oh and the word is sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the lucky numbers pair up. For example, $127406$ is lucky; so is $406127$. Their sum is 
$$
(127 + 406)\times (7 \times 11 \times 13).
$$

The ones that don't pair up, like $123123$ are themselves divisible by $7$.

Comment: What would be the specific pair condition? Would you dimply flip the 2 groups of 3 digits?

Comment: Sure. When you swap the first three digits for the last three either you get the same number or a different number. When you get a different number you have a pair.